# MongoDB updating fields in nested array

Tags: php, mongodb, database

MongoDB updating fields in nested array

How can I set "play" to "play photo" in the `photos` array?

I only know its `_id`.

```
"_id": ObjectId("4f41a5c7c32810e404000000"),
"albums": [
{
    "_id": ObjectId("4f545d1bc328103812000000"),
    "name": "album1" ,
    "photos":[{
        "_id": ObjectId("4f545d1bc328103812d00000"),
        "name":"travel photo"
    },{
        "_id": ObjectId("4f545d1bc328103812c00000"),
        "name":"play"
    }]
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("4f545f56c328103c12000000"),
    "name": "album2" 
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("4f545f68c328103012000000"),
    "name": "album3" 
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("4f546642c328103c12000001"),
    "name": "album4" 
}]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. The positional operator is only available for the first array in your document hierarchy. As such you cannot manipulate individual elements of deeper nester arrays.

It's a known issue and is scheduled for development here : https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831

Until that time you'll have to normalize your schema a bit I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks,
but I may not change my schema.
I will pull the element,modify,and push back.
although its Inefficient.

Comment: That's an option but has serious concurrency issues (one write can overwrite the results of a concurrent write) so use with care.

Answer (score 18):

> This issue has been resolved. Feature of updating fields
> inside nested array of objects, is available in MongoDB 3.6+ versions.
> Look positional operators(all and with identifier) [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/).

```
//Update all docs in collection matching photo name "play" to "play photo"
db.collectioname.update(
    {},
    { $set: { "albums.$[].photos.$[photo_field].name": "play photo" } },
    { arrayFilters: [  {"photo_field.name": "play"} ], multi: true}
);

//Update this specific doc given in question matching photo name "play" to "play photo"
db.collectioname.update(
    {"_id" : ObjectId("4f41a5c7c32810e404000000")},
    { $set: { "albums.$[].photos.$[photo_field].name": "play photo" } },
    { arrayFilters: [  {"photo_field.name": "play"} ]}
);
```

> This is for the help of people coming here after MongoDB 3.6

Comment: what does `photo_field` in your example mean?
Does it mean go through all fields in photo until you find `name`?

Comment: Yes, it will go through each index of albums and then photos and match "play" and then sets it to "play photo".

Answer (score 0):

Tonilin You Cant Update this type of array directly for this you need to find the index of that array in which you want to update like if you want to update `name` as `play photo` then you have to find the index of `photos` where name is `play`.
For this I used this code like:

```
$m = new Mongo();
$db=$m->yourdatabase;
//testarray is my collection name
$result=$db->testarray->find();
$index='';
foreach($result as $res)
{
    if(array_key_exists("albums",$res))
    {
        foreach($res['albums'] as $ralbum)
        {
            if(array_key_exists("photos",$ralbum))
            {
                foreach($ralbum['photos'] as $k=>$rphotos)
                {
                    if(array_key_exists("name",$rphotos))
                        if($rphotos['name']=='play')
                            $index=$k;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
//echo $index;
```

// Now to update this value in your database use this code...

```
if($index!=='')
{
    //Run like this in Shell
    //db.testarray.update({"albums.photos._id":ObjectId("4f545d1bc328103812d00000")},{'$set':{"albums.$.photos.1.name":"play132"}})
    $condition=array("albums.photos._id"=>new MongoId("4f545d1bc328103812d00000"));
    $data=array('$set'=>array("albums.$.photos.".$index.".name"=>"play photo"));
    $result=$db->testarray->update($condition,$data);
    $status=$db->Command(array('getlasterror'=>1));
    print_r($status);
}
```