# MongoDB - Update field in an array object based on nested array's field value

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to update a field inside array of objects, where field in nested array is equal to a value.

My goal here is to set the `picture` field a new url, where `value` field in `valueList` is `oldRed`

**Product schema:**

```
{
    variations: [{
        id: 1,
        picture: 'https://example.picture.com',
        valueList: [{
            name: 'color',
            value: 'oldRed'
        }, {
            name: 'size',
            value: 'M'
        }]

    }, {
        id: 2,
        picture: 'https://example.picture.com',
        valueList: [{
            name: 'color',
            value: 'black'
        }, {
            name: 'size',
            value: 'M'
        }]

    }]
}
```

The closest I get is thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51596944/5600899), where I update all my nested array fields that contains :'oldRed' . But my final goal is to update other field `picture`, based on nested array field.

```
db.Product.findOneAndUpdate({
    _id: '123'
}, {
    $set: {
        'variations.$[].valueList.$[nameField].value': 'newRed'
    }
}, {
    arrayFilters: [{
        'nameField.value': 'oldRed'
    }],
    new: true
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this :

```
db.Product.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: 123 },
        {
            $set: {
                'variations.$[item].valueList.$[nameField].value': 'newRed',
                'variations.$[item].picture': 'newURL' // item is each object in variations which is being checked in arrayFilters.
            }
        },
        {
            arrayFilters: [{ 'item.valueList.value': 'oldRed' }, { 'nameField.value': 'oldRed' }],
            new: true
        }
   )
```

**Colletion Data :**

```
{
    "_id" : 123,
    "variations" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "picture" : "https://example.picture.com",
            "valueList" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "color",
                    "value" : "oldRed"
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "size",
                    "value" : "M"
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "color",
                    "value" : "oldRed"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "picture" : "https://example.picture.com",
            "valueList" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "color",
                    "value" : "black"
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "size",
                    "value" : "M"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 3,
            "picture" : "https://example3.picture.com",
            "valueList" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "color",
                    "value" : "oldRed"
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "size",
                    "value" : "M"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 123,
    "variations" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "picture" : "newURL",
            "valueList" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "color",
                    "value" : "newRed"
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "size",
                    "value" : "M"
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "color",
                    "value" : "newRed"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "picture" : "https://example.picture.com",
            "valueList" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "color",
                    "value" : "black"
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "size",
                    "value" : "M"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 3,
            "picture" : "newURL",
            "valueList" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "color",
                    "value" : "newRed"
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "size",
                    "value" : "M"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think in mongoose it will be `new: true` to return updated document, if using mongodb driver or shell try `returnNewDocument: true`..